# In android altBeacon didRangeBeaconsInRegion, beacon size always shows 0. What's wrong?

Tags: android, kotlin, beacon, altbeacon

When I use other commercial beacon scanners, beacons are caught normally, but when I use this source code I made, they are not caught at all.

It is confirmed that the "didRangeBeaconsInRegion" function continues to work, but the number of beacons always returns 0. Please check what the problem is.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

TextView textView;

private BeaconManager beaconManager;

String beaconUUID="00000000000000000000000000000054"; // beacon -uuid
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

private String TAG = "CHS_BEA";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=findViewById(R.id.tv_message);


    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25\""));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    //beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
    beaconManager.bind(this);

}// onCreate()..

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
    Log.i(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect Start");
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {

        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion Start -> " + region.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion beacons -> " + beacons.size());

        }
    });

   beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "didEnterRegion - 비콘 연결됨", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textView.setText("Beacon connected");

        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "didExitRegion - 비콘 연결 끊김", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textView.setText("Beacon disconnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }

    });


    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("beacon",
                null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }


   try
    {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("beacon",
                null, null, null));
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
    }
}// onBeaconServiceConnect()..


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}


@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
}
```

}// MainActivity class..``

Comment: This question is so common, and the reasons for the problem so varied, that I created a [troubleshooting guide](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html) at the very top of the documentation for the library.  Please check what the problem is.

Comment: @davidgyoung I checked the documentation, checked everything, but the same problem occurs.